# why is my jetty-deployed war looking for org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory?

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

I am trying to deploy a war file from inside an embedded jetty server.  I have the commons-logging jar in the WEB-INF/lib of my WAR. The init method of the JspServlet is looking for this org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory class.  I'm using Jetty 7.5.

In researching how to deploy wars with embedded Jetty, I've also seen problems getting jsps to work. Could this be related to that, since it's the JspServlet that is looking for this class?

The WAR is extremely simple, basically the HelloWorld example for Spring MVC 3. I'm just prototyping at this point.  The Jetty Server is also pretty bare-bones, here it is :

```
public class JettyServer extends Server {

    Server server;
    int port;

    public JettyServer(int port) {
        server = new Server(port);

        WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
        webapp.setContextPath("/");
        webapp.setWar("webapps/myWar.war");
        server.setHandler(webapp);
    }

    public void startServer() throws Exception {
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an old JspServlet somewhere in your build (the error you pasted is from the JspServlet from Tomcat 6!)

Make sure you use the same server side JSP support jars that the `jetty-distribution--7.5.0.v2011090` uses.

Here's the list that Jetty ships with..

```
[jetty-distribution-7.5.0.v20110901]$ sha1sum lib/jsp/*.jar
84d1928dbcf564dab574577ac454ef7cacec2b9a  lib/jsp/com.sun.el_1.0.0.v201004190952.jar
5618cc694d1e1ce8956fa441b551c8b690547fab  lib/jsp/ecj-3.6.jar
b4628cebfe2612db3c646ffbde43029fd3d0d7a0  lib/jsp/javax.el_2.1.0.v201004190952.jar
2c891df2ef4882fd250d34d7a873061bf4c3d9bc  lib/jsp/javax.servlet.jsp_2.1.0.v201004190952.jar
582f581db2e9646d1f61313f3d96ced8c0acdac5  lib/jsp/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl_1.2.0.v201004190952.jar
3bd086e9e7bdcff906ad25fed4e5805ad101fc5e  lib/jsp/jetty-jsp-2.1-7.5.0.v20110901.jar
3ec4b7e53369ed311a3171fe6b73beb773a46e25  lib/jsp/jsp-impl-2.1.3-b10.jar
b070c22fe31d84de75135da39faff654fe42c933  lib/jsp/org.apache.taglibs.standard.glassfish_1.2.0.v201004190952.jar
```

Jetty uses the Jasper compiler from Apache with modifications by Glassfish.

Comment: That was it! Thanks much. I had forgotten to add the libs in the /jsp directory of the jetty distribution. I wish Eclipse had a way to add all jars in subdirectories for user libraries. I'm also curious where that older JspServlet came from.